# In validation use another div for error message

Tags: yii2, yii-validation

When I make validation - I have two fields: age_from and age_to.
but they have only one error field (help-block) "age_to".
In model there are rules:

```
['age_from',  'dateFunc'],
['age_to',  'dateFunc'],
public function dateFunc(){
if($this->age_from < 1){
    $this->addError('age_to', 'error message1');
}
if($this->age_to < 1){
    $this->addError('age_to', 'error message2');
}
```

Problem - when the first field has an error it's not a red border.
Is exist a possibility to make a red border for an unvalidated field but the message to show in another div?

Comment: when you add error to a specific attribute it would be shown inside the `help-block` div corresponding to that attribute in the activeform. what you are trying is to highlight the field `age_from` with a red border and show the message under the `age_to` only if the `age_to` is invalid otherwise show it under the `age_from` but the border will only be turned red for the `age_from` field? is that correct?

Comment: Yes, so when "age_from" is invalid, it must be red, but the error message must be shown in "age_to" or a third div, and, if "age_to" is valid in the same time, "age_to" must not be red, while it's help-block is shown, but with message for "age_from"